# How to prevent W3C Validator from parsing internal CSS?

Tags: html, css, validation, w3c-validation

The [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) didn't always parse internal CSS. I know this because, just recently pages that used to have no errors nor warnings now have *newly found* CSS errors.

Hence, my question is: Does any ignore code exist for the W3C Validator, similar to

`<!--googleoff: all--><!--googleon: all-->`

for Google, to prevent W3C from parsing internal CSS?

**Sample "Internal" CSS code:**

```
<style> 

@-ms-viewport
    {
        width:device-width;
    }

button, input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"]
    {
        padding-top:8px !important;
        padding-right:14px !important;
        padding-bottom:9px !important;
        padding-left:14px !important;

        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;

        -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(159,159,159,0.5);
        -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(159,159,159,0.5);
        -khtml-box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(159,159,159,0.5);
        box-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(159,159,159,0.5);

        -webkit-border-radius:2px;
        -moz-border-radius:2px;
        -khtml-border-radius:2px;
        border-radius:2px;

        border-width:1px;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#BCBCBC;

        background:#f0f0f0;
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%, #E0E0E0 100%);
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f0f0f0), color-stop(100%,#E0E0E0));
        background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%,#E0E0E0 100%);
        background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%,#E0E0E0 100%);
        background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%,#E0E0E0 100%);
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0f0f0 0%,#E0E0E0 100%);
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f0f0f0', endColorstr='#E0E0E0',GradientType=0 );

        color:#535353 !important;
        font-size:0.928em !important;
        font-weight:normal !important;
        line-height:normal !important;
    }

button:hover, input[type="button"]:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="reset"]:hover, button:focus, input[type="button"]:focus, input[type="submit"]:focus, input[type="reset"]:focus
    {
        background:#f8f8f8;
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8 0%, #E1E1E1 100%);
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f8f8f8), color-stop(100%,#E1E1E1));
        background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8 0%,#E1E1E1 100%);
        background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8 0%,#E1E1E1 100%);
        background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8 0%,#E1E1E1 100%);
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f8f8f8 0%,#E1E1E1 100%);
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f8f8f8', endColorstr='#E1E1E1',GradientType=0 );
    }

button:active, input[type="button"]:active, input[type="submit"]:active, input[type="reset"]:active
    {
        -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(205,205,205,1);
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(205,205,205,1);
        -khtml-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(205,205,205,1);
        box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(205,205,205,1);

        background:#E0E0E0;

        text-decoration:none !important;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Can you include a minimal example that gives such an error? I tried several things but can’t reproduce it.

Comment: @unor I just added it. Sorry for the wait, but I've been busy with work, lately. And so I haven't checked back in for a while. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Thanks, I can reproduce it with https://validator.w3.org/nu/, but not with https://validator.w3.org/. Are you using the Nu validator (i.e., checking HTML5)?

Comment: @unor I'm not sure, because I usually include a link on the web page itself that automatically checks for validity (e.g. `<a href="https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https://card.jamesandersonjr.com" target="_blank">Valid HTML 5 code</a>` ). I don't usually go to the w3 validator site directly to check the page manually. Can I change the link prefix I use to validate, to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking a HTML5 document with https://validator.w3.org/, you’ll get redirected to https://validator.w3.org/nu/, so the latter is likely the validator you are using.

WHATWG’s HTML spec [introduced](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/3024) this requirement for the content of a [`style` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-style-element):

> The [child text content](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-child-text-content) of a `style` element must be that of a [conformant style sheet](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax/#conform-classes).

This means: **If you want to have a valid WHATWG-HTML document, your CSS in the `style` element needs to be valid, too.** This wasn’t the case previously.

However, W3C’s HTML spec doesn’t have this requirement for the [`style` element](https://w3c.github.io/html/document-metadata.html#the-style-element), as of 2017-12-26. Unless they add that requirement, too, W3C-HTML documents would still be valid even if they contain invalid CSS in `style` elements. Then maybe the validator instance hosted by the W3C will disable this CSS checking feature.

(Some days ago, a user [asked for a switch in the validator to disable checking the CSS](https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/585). The maintainer "will look into this".)